# Nested ListView Only Running First getView()

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to create a nested comments system, but I have encountered an issue. I have a main ListView to display all the top level comments, and every comment XML contains a sub ListView with adjusted padding. The nested comments load, but only the first returned comment loads for each parent comment. I have done some debugging and it appears as if all the data is being sent to the ListView ArrayAdapter, but getView() is only being run for the first item. Is it possible to force a reload of the ListView, or is there a better way to do what I am trying?

Below is my current code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"

android:background="#ff2b2b2b"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingEnd="0dp"
android:scrollbars="none">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/author"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ccrama"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/commentLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="COMMENT"
    android:textSize="14dp" />

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/commentsListUnder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
    android:background="#ff2b2b2b"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

My ArrayAdapter looks like this

```
public class CommentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CommentNode> {
public CommentAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CommentNode> users) {
    super(context, 0, users);
    main = context;
    this.users = users;

}
ArrayList<CommentNode> users;



Context main;

CommentNode user;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    user = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.comment, parent, false);
    }
    TextView author = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);
    TextView comm = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentLine);
    TextView upvote = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.upvotePost);

    author.setText(user.getComment().getAuthor());
    comm.setText(user.getComment().getBody());
    upvote.setText(user.getComment().getScore() + "");

    ArrayList<CommentNode> comments = new ArrayList<CommentNode>();
    CommentNode comment = user;
    for (CommentNode node : comment.walkTree(TraversalMethod.BREADTH_FIRST)) {
        if (node.getParent().getComment().getId() == comment.getComment().getId()) {
            comments.add(node);
        }

    }

    //The above method IS returning all the correctly leveled comments

    CommentAdapter adapter = new CommentAdapter(main, comments);
    ListView listView = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentsListUnder);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return convertView;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return users == null ? 0 : users.size();
} }
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: probably what  you are looking for is the `ExpandableListView`

Comment: Thank you Blackbelt, but from what I've read, the ExpandableListView only allows for one child node, but in my case I need to have a ListView inside a previous ListView. Please let me know if that is not the case.

Comment: probably you misread it (or I misunderstood you)

Comment: Actually I think you are right. I will try that method and report back here if it doesn't work. Will keep the question open until then

Comment: @ccrama you can have multiple items in an each group of an `ExpandableListView`. You will have one header (Your main comment) then multiple child elements in each (The reply comments)

Comment: Ah alright. Will try this method then :)

Comment: @Blackbelt that method is working for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This can be done without using ExpandableListView.
What is happening is as you have emebedded a list view inside another, it is getting shrunk, what you need to do is dynamically adjust the height of your inner list view based on the number of items. Do this in your outside adapter:

```
OrderDetailAdapter adapter = new OrderDetailAdapter(context,0,orderDetails);
        int numberOfItems = orderDetails.size();
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = holder.listView.getLayoutParams();
        int pixels = (int) (80 * scale);
        int dpPixels = (int) (0.1 * scale);
        params.height =numberOfItems * pixels + (numberOfItems - 1) * dpPixels;
        holder.listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        holder.listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Where OrderDetailAdapter is adapter for the inner list.
The scale is obtained internally:

```
scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

which is a float variable;

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using `ExpandableListView` instead of `ListView`.

Comment: is you display your top comment as a Group view in `ExpandableListView`  and all comments as children views ?

Comment: I think your answer will more helpful IF you submit your solution with code